# Conditional column based on 2 different columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table in the query editor that has succession plans, it has incumbents and their potential successors. Some incumbents have multiple successors so an incumbent may have multiple lines denoting one employee each, if an incumbent has 10 successors they get 10 lines, a third cloumn indicates the successors gender. I need a 4th custom column that says if the incumbent has any females as a successor at all, so even if they have 9 males and 1 female I want all 10 rows in the 4th column to say "has female on plan" for that incumbent. How do I do this? I was able to do it in DAX but I need to do it in powerquery to merge and connect the data with other important variables.

I honestly have no idea how to use powerquery nearly as efficiently as DAX, So beyond just pasting the dax formula and tying to make it work I haven't done much outside of trying to google it. Here is the DAX Formula for reference

IF(
COUNTROWS(
FILTER(
'Succession',
'Succession'[Employee ID] = EARLIER('Succession'[Employee ID]) &&
'Succession'[Female (YES/NO)] = "YES"
)
) > 0,
"Yes",
"No"
)

Comment: Please provide data samples (source and estimated output)